# Is it possible to replicate the MS SQL server users to Active Directory

Tags: sql-server

Currently, MS SQL Server is the only user store. We don't have an Active Directory yet, so I want to replicate all the log-in users from MS SQL users to AD on prem.

I'm currently using only SQL Server logins and don't have Windows authentication. That's why I need to replicate all the users from SQL Server to Active Directory so I can integrate the users with third-party software that doesn't support SQL. I need to replicate the user to an Active Directory because LDAP is only supported for user integration.

Comment: Yes, this is right. I'm currently using SQL Server login and don't have Windows authentication. That's why I need to replicate all the users from SQL Server to Active Directory so I can integrate the users with third-party software that doesn't support SQL. That's why I need to replicate the user to an Active Directory because LDAP is only supported for user integration.